# How to return observable of string

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-services

Have an api method that returns a simple string.  I am implementing a method in my angular service that needs to return an obserable

The simple string doesnt map directly into the observable.  How can I return an observable with the simple string result from the api?

```
public setLineItemListApproval(lines : OrderLinesModel) : Observable<string>{

    let actionUrl = this.apiBaseURL + '/mycontroller/actionmethod1';
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json'
        })
    };

    return this.httpClient.post<string>(actionUrl, lines, httpOptions).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));

}
```

Comment: Where do you want to return it? In some component? Or within the same service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

- Include `responseType: 'text` in the `options` argument
- Inline the options with the call
- Use the non-generic overload of `post` as `responseType: 'text'` option now dictates which one is used as well as the return type in the `Observable` response

```
public setLineItemListApproval(lines : OrderLinesModel) : Observable<string>{

    let actionUrl = this.apiBaseURL + '/mycontroller/actionmethod1';
    return this.httpClient.post(actionUrl, lines, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json'
        }),
        responseType: 'text'
    }).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For accomplishing this:

1. Add responseType: 'text' in the options argument

This simple change should work

Comment: See my answer below. By only adding `responseType: 'text'` you will get an error when you run `ng build` because the types are not assignable. You must do all 3 of the steps I have in my answer if you want the code to build.